# How can I use vertorisation to have a function normalize columns of a cell array iterating through different max values for each column?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, cell-array

I am trying to use vectorisation to have a function normalize values of a cell array throughout different max values for each column.

Suppose I have a cell array called `holdArray`,

```
holdArray =  {1   2   3   4   5   6
              7   8   9   10  11  12
              13  14  15  16  17  18
              19  20  21  22  23  24}
```

and suppose I have another cell array containing the max values of each column of `holdArray` called `maxVal`,

```
maxVal = {19   20   21   22   23   24}
```

I am trying to normalize the columns in `holdArray` using the values in `maxVal`, i.e every value in the first column in `holdArray` will be normalized using the first value in `maxVal` and so on.

I know I can easily do this using a for loop but because the arrays I will be working with will be very large I would much rather use vectorisation.
currently I have done it this way where D is just an array to hold the normalized values `D = cellfun(@(x)(x./maxVal(1,:)), holdArray, 'UniformOutput', false)`

Which returns this output:

```
D = 

    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]
    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]
    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]
    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]
```

Meaning it normalises each value in the column across all the values in `maxVal`

Any explanation onto how to use vectorisation to get this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using a `cell` for doubles? Use `cell2mat` to convert it to a `matrix`, then vectorisation is easy...

```
holdArray =  {1   2   3   4   5   6
              7   8   9   10  11  12
              13  14  15  16  17  18
              19  20  21  22  23  24};

holdArray = cell2mat(holdArray); % Converts cell to matrix

maxVal = {19   20   21   22   23   24};
maxVal = cell2mat(maxVal);

% Make matrix same size as holdArray but entire column is maxVal
maxVal = repmat(maxVal, size(holdArray,1),1); 

% Element-wise division to normalise
holdArray = holdArray./maxVal;

% ans =
%
%  [0.0526    0.1000    0.1429    0.1818    0.2174    0.2500
%   0.3684    0.4000    0.4286    0.4545    0.4783    0.5000
%   0.6842    0.7000    0.7143    0.7273    0.7391    0.7500
%   1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000]

% If you really want it back in a cell, you can use mat2cell
holdArray = mat2Cell(holdArray, size(holdArray,1));
```

Since `max` operates on columns anyway, you don't need cell/vector `maxVal` at all, and the entire code could be condensed to this:

```
holdArray = {1   2  ... };  % abbreviated, use above definition
holdArray = cell2mat(holdArray);
holdArray = holdArray ./ repmat(max(holdArray), size(holdArray,1), 1); 
holdArray = mat2Cell(holdArray, size(holdArray,1));
```